.NET Soap web Reference: "The specified type was not recognized"
 System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
 (1, 640). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type
 was not recognized:
 name='webservices.soap.types.company.Type_company',
 namespace='http://rpc.xml.coldfusion', at <GetCompaniesReturn
 xmlns=''>.

I get the error after this.Invoke("GetCompanies", new object[] {CompanyUUID, CompanyName});is called, is there any way to debug it and see what's breaking? or somehow define the type?
I really don't know where to look for, the debugger doesn't go into anything after the call.
Unfortunately this is an external third-party SOAP service and the code base is legacy.
